# DataSet transformation to new DataSet group by (x)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, dataset

I have DataSet. 
it returns date, and value by date.

for ex:

```
01.01.2009   454
02.01.2009   785
03.01.2009   475
----------   ---
30.01.2009   523
```

I need new DataSet, that group by week. 
for ex:

```
1 Week 1-7   2017
2 Week 7-15  4586  
-----------------
5 Week 24-30 1482
```

Week begin from monday.

not importand only for this example, important that, how group by (x) initial DataSet.

Please, any Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either iterate by the original dataset, gather the info and enter it to the new dataset, 
or add a week column to the database, and query the table using group by to get the dataset that you want.

Comment: I'm interested in first variant.

Comment: so just iterate through all the rows. if they are ordered by date it is even easier, create a new dataset with the new columns you need and build it row by row.